# как остановить работу хендлера телеграмм бота

Tags: python, aiogram

я пишу телеграмм бота и столкнулся с проблемой что когда вводишь команду /weather ты должен ввести название города и он через API выводит сводку погоды но как остановить этот хендлер я не знаю, эта функция не заканчивается, она работает после ввода команды /weather
помогите остановить async def reaction(message: types.Message): что бы после ввода названия одного города функция заканчивалась
вот код:

```
 import requests
import datetime
from config import token1
from config import open_weather_token
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor


bot = Bot(token=token1)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет, меня зовут Аркадий, что бы увидеть список команд введи  /commands")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['commands'])
async def list_commands(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Вот, держи список команд\n/start - преветсвующее сообщение\n/commands - список команд")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def weather(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Напиши мне название города и я пришлю сводку погоды!")

@dp.message_handler()
async def reaction(message: types.Message):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric"
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"
        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
            f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
            f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
            f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
            f"***Хорошего дня!***"
            )

    except:
        await message.reply("\U00002620 Проверьте название города \U00002620")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вам нужен state() - https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html
вы отдельно создайте бота по примеру, побалуйтесь, разберетесь быстро. удачи

Comment: я прочитал документацию и не понял для чего и как использовать state()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать FSM для этого, вот примерно так это будет выглядеть.

```
import requests
import datetime

from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from config import token1
from config import open_weather_token
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher, FSMContext
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token=token1)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class StateWeather(StatesGroup):
    weather = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет, меня зовут Аркадий, что бы увидеть список команд введи  /commands")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['commands'])
async def list_commands(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Вот, держи список команд\n/start - преветсвующее сообщение\n/commands - список команд")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def weather(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Напиши мне название города и я пришлю сводку погоды!")
    await StateWeather.weather.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=StateWeather.weather)
async def reaction(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric"
        )
        data = r.json()

        city = data["name"]
        cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

        weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"
        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

        await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
                            f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
                            f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
                            f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
                            f"***Хорошего дня!***"
                            )
        await state.finish()
    except:
        await message.reply("\U00002620 Проверьте название города \U00002620")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Если кратко, то мы создали StateWeather который наследовали от StatesGroup и в нем создали определенный стейт, который вы можете назвать как хотите, ну как и название класса. Дальше в weather мы запустили стейт и добавили фильтр на ваш пустой хендлер, который срабатывает исключительно если запущено наше состояние (а также если то, что отправил юзер, является текстом). После верного срабатывания хендлера мы закрываем стейт.
Всё.

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо что ответили и помогли , попробовал запустить, после ввода команды /weather бот выводит сообщение, но после отправки названия города ничего не происходит, а в консоли появляется следующее сообщение `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\state.py:57: FSMStorageWarning: You haven’t set any storage yet so no states and no data will be saved.
You can connect MemoryStorage for debug purposes or non-essential data.
  await state.set_state(self.state)`

Comment: storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage) при создании экземпляра диспатчера